# I am looking a search that offers Previews of the content of Files

Tags: windows, pdf, google-chrome-extensions, onedrive, google-drive

When i search for keywords in text files most platforms only display a list of the files the keyword is in. (Thats the case in Google drive, windows 7, ms one drive, google books on pc ) I need to find a way get a preview of each appearecene of the keyword and its context.

Adobe reader offers this, but obviously just for pdf files.

any suggestions how to do this?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AstroGrep. You can search for keywords in multiple file formats. It shows you the files where it finds the keyword, the line where the keywords is located and a preview.

[image]