# Complex searches over multiple documents with multiple formats

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, pdf, search

Ok, so let's say you have to search 10+ documents for a certain term or a set of terms.

Let's say further, that the documents have various formats (.pdf, .xlxs, .docx, .xls, .doc, etc.)

Is there some way to do an advanced search like this, where all the hits are listed and you can click on a link to view each of the hits in the various documents and then return to the list of hits?

Example: I want to find "sufferin succotash" in this list of docs:

Pumpkin Recipes.doc
Fall Cooking Delights.docx
Warner Bros Recipes pre-1980.pdf 
Warner Bros Recipes post-1980.pdf
Betty Crocker.xlsx
MyfavoriteSquashes2112.xls
NSACookbook.pdf
BetterCookingwithcornmeal.MDB
CodingandCookingwithEspresso.Java

It would be really cool if there was some kind of advanced search that would search these documents with the option for wild cards and deliver a list of hits that one could click on to view and then return to the original hit list to select another potential hit.

Comment: Does this helps you?  http://superuser.com/questions/1132343/i-am-looking-a-search-that-offers-previews-of-the-content-of-files/1132379#1132379

Answer (score 1):

What is your OS?

If you run Windows 7 or later, you can do an advanced search within the file contents, then open any file from the list of results and see whether it works for you. Selecting the "Contents" view will allow the search string to become highlighted among adjacent context and help you even better.

---

In order to enable searching within the file contents, open Start and begin typing "Indexing Options"; then open the Advanced settings, select the File Types tab, and check the "Index Properties and File Contents" option.

*For Windows 7:* You may need to enable the PDF IFilter, information can be found [in this already answered question.](https://superuser.com/questions/402673/how-to-search-inside-pdfs-with-windows-search)